# The compiler failed with error code 2000

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For those who still have lots of legacy code as I do in .NET 1.1, has anyone found a solution for this issue:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=90240

Details are usually as follows:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Basic .NET Compiler version 7.10.6001.4
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 1.1.4322.2407
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1987-2002. All rights reserved.

vbc : Command line error BC2017 : could not find library 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\temporary asp.net files\...\...\...\*.dll
vbc : Fatal error BC2000 : compiler initialization failed unexpectedly: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The directory given in the command line will not exist, which makes sense given the error message.   The problematic part is that everything works with a full rebuild.   Since the "work around" is so easy, Microsoft of course is not going to fix the problem for .net 1.1.

To everyone who pre-emptively suggests an upgrade to .net 2.0+, that is not an acceptable solution, due to time limits and resources.   To those who say that is not an acceptable excuse, go find another thread, not every company is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an actual fix for this issue, only various work-arounds.

It is a known bug in the 1.0 and 1.1 frameworks, which does not exist in 2.0 (or higher) frameworks.  Upgrading to 2.0 (or higher) would of course be the better solution (as I'm sure you're aware), however, as you state you cannot do that.

As well as there being work-arounds for the issue, there are other settings that you may or may not have configured that can help to mitigate the problem somewhat.

This thread:
[BC2017 - Compiler Error - BC2000](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vb/browse_thread/thread/77facb0b57798228/8416d0e4346450f4?q=BC2017+-+Compiler+Error+-+BC2000#8416d0e4346450f4)
(and particularly the post directly linked to) should give some options for possible reconfiguration changes to help mitigate the issue.